# Generators of permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I want to proof that $S_n$ is generated by the set of transpositions ${(1,2),(1,3), \ldots , (1,n)}$ using that $(k,j) = (1,k)(1,j)(1,j)$ but I don't know how to continue. I know this is a easy problem but I dont know what to do.

Comment: $(1, k) (1, j) (1, j) = (1, k)$, you want $(1, j) (1, k) (1, j) = (j, k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ can be written as the product of disjoint cycles.  Any cycle $(a_1, \dotsc, a_m) \in S_n$ can be written as the product of transpositions by noting
$$ (a_1, a_2, a_3,\dotsc, a_m) = (a_m, a_1)(a_{m-1}, a_1)\dotsc(a_3, a_1)(a_2, a_1). $$
Therefore, the set of all transpositions generate $S_n$.  Since
$$ (1, j)(1, k)(1, j) = (j, k), $$
the set generated by $(1, 2), \dotsc, (1, n)$ contains all transpositions.  Therefore, the set generated by $(1, 2), \dotsc, (1, n)$ is $S_n$.